# Passing through an array with POST Java

Tags: java, api, httpurlconnection

I'll get straight to the point. 
I'm trying to use an API that requires an Array to be passed through just so you can have multiple objects passed through in a single API call. I keep getting 400 errors whenever I try doing this.

Not 100% sure if I'm doing it right, tried looking into it a lot but can't find anyone with the same problem. Sorry for all the text but it should make everything more straight forward. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Firstly, here's what the array should look like:

```
{
   "listings":[
      {
         "intent":0,
         "item": {
               "quality": 6,
               "item_name": "Name",
               "craf": 1,
               "priceindex":"currency"
                 },
         "currencies":{
            "m":1
                      },
         "details":"Test",
         "BO":1,
         "offers":1,
         "promoted":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is how I tried making the array:

```
    JSONObject listing = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject itemObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject itemDetails = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject currency = new JSONObject();

    itemObject.put("intent", intent);

    itemDetails.put("quality", quality);
    itemDetails.put("item_name", item_name);
    itemDetails.put("craf", craftable);
    itemDetails.put("princeindex", princeindex);

    itemObject.put("item", itemDetails);

    currency.put("m", currencies);

    itemObject.put("details", "Test");
    itemObject.put("BO", buyout);
    itemObject.put("offers", offers);
    itemObject.put("promoted", promoted);
    itemObject.put("currencies", currency);

    listing.put("listings", itemObject);

    Set(listing);
```

The actual code for the POST call is here:

```
URL url = new URL("https://backpack.tf/api/classifieds/list/v1");
        Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("token","#########");
        params.put("listings", this.listings);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0)
                postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
```

Edit(The 400 error):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://backpack.tf/api/classifieds/list/v1?token=5863418ee3387722bc77bcc0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Scraper.APIFinalBOT.set(APIFinalBOT.java:48)
    at Scraper.nodeJSBotPricer.Set(nodeJSBotPricer.java:97)
    at Scraper.nodeJSBotPricer.main(nodeJSBotPricer.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://backpack.tf/api/classifieds/list/v1?token=5863418ee3387722bc77bcc0
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at Scraper.APIFinalBOT.set(APIFinalBOT.java:43)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Have you considered using a library like Jackson or Gson to help you with this?

Comment: Can you post to this url using postman, for example? And where do you get 404, I don't see any code to deal with response here.

Comment: By the way, 404 means that the URL is wrong, most likely... Did you print out the json you made, though? You never add a JSONArray

Comment: Updated the post with the error, and I haven't tried those Cricket.

Comment: And that's what I thought Cricket but this is definitely the correct website...

Comment: Not sure why I even bothered changing the website tbh. Here is the documentation for the API. https://backpack.tf/api/docs/create_listings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is *almost* correct.

You are calling

```
 https://backpack.tf/api/classifieds/list/v1/
```

When the documented API endpoint does not have the trailing slash.

```
 https://backpack.tf/api/classifieds/list/v1
```

Testing these in a browser I get a 404 for the URL with the slash and a "please use POST" error when the slash is removed, as expected.

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier as well but ended up getting 400 errors...Here's the error: https://pastebin.com/cRdVqdDZ

Comment: Well, that's means you are hitting the correct endpoint, but it's not processing your request properly. The slash version is certainly wrong. Remove the slash and work on sending correct request data.

Comment: What's bothering me a bit is, I used some program called Postman and entered the array I posted above in manually in it's raw form, and it worked. So not sure what's up. Thank you though

Comment: Didn't think I could do that since it says I have to submit an array as the input

Comment: I would print the form data string that your code is creating, test it with postman, if it fails, make adjustments util it works, then reflect changes back into your code.

Comment: Oh that's not a bad idea, alright thanks I'll give that a try.

Comment: The API says it will accept a fully JSON request when you send the right header. Maybe you'll need to switch to JSON to avoid problems with the list.

Comment: After messing around with the String, got it to display the same stuff with postman finally. But still won't work in my code so now the problem lies with how I submit the POST request. I'll try that now

Comment: Can't get it to work, 400 errors continue. Found somebody who may have done it before so I'm going to see if he can help me, thank you for the attempted help so far though

Comment: Well, apparently Postman allows you to export the code to make the call in like every language...So it's working now :P That would have been useful 4h ago. Used a completely different method. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: No problem :) Glad i could help. Or at least create the illusion of helping :)